# Apache Camel - Pass Filename from route1 to route2 which FTPs

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have a requirement of generating a file from webservice and FTP to a location.

Route1:

```
from("direct:start")
    .routeId("generateFileRoute")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(URL))
    .setHeader("Authorization", simple(APP_KEY))
    .to(URL)
    .unmarshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
    .marshal(bindyCsvDataFormat)
    .to(fileDirLoc + "?fileName=RMA_OUT_${date:now:MMddyyyy_HHmmss}.csv&noop=true");
```

---

Route 2: FTP Route

```
from("file://"+header("CamelFileNameProduced"))
    .routeId("ftpRoute")
    .to("sftp://FTP_HOST/DIR?username=???&password=???)
```

To start the route

```
Exchange exchange = template.request("direct:start", null);

Object filePathObj = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameProduced");

if (filePathObj != null) { // Makesure Route1 has created the file
    camelContext.startRoute("ftpRoute");     // Start FTP route
    template.send(exchange); // Send exchange from Route1 to Route2
}
```

The above code worked when I hard-coded the location in FTP route.
Can someone please help, how can I pipeline these 2 routes and pass output of Route 1 ("File Name") to Route2 for FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass headers to the `file` endpoint, it just doesn't work like that. Also, `from("file://...")` cannot contain dynamic values in its path, i.e. placeholders of any kind, here's a quote from the [official Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html#File2-URIformat):

> Camel supports only endpoints configured with a starting directory. So the directoryName must be a directory. If you want to consume a single file only, you can use the fileName option e.g., by setting fileName=thefilename. **Also, the starting directory must not contain dynamic expressions with ${} placeholders.** Again use the fileName option to specify the dynamic part of the filename.

My suggestion would be to either send to FTP directly, if you are not doing any additional CSV file processing:

```
from("direct:start")
    .routeId("generateFileRoute")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(URL))
    .setHeader("Authorization", simple(APP_KEY))
    .to(URL)
    .unmarshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
    .marshal(bindyCsvDataFormat)
    .to("sftp://FTP_HOST/DIR?username=???&password=??&fileName=RMA_OUT_${date:now:MMddyyyy_HHmmss}.csv");
```

Or to change Route 2 definition from `file` to `direct`:

```
from("direct:ftp-send")
    .routeId("ftpRoute")
    .pollEnrich("file:destination?fileName=${headers.CamelFileNameProduced}")
    .to("sftp://FTP_HOST/DIR?username=???&password=??&fileName=${headers.CamelFileName}")
```

or to change the definition of Route 2 to pick up only the generated files:

```
from("file://" + fileDirLoc + "?antInclude=RMA_OUT_*.csv")
    .routeId("ftpRoute")
    .to("sftp://FTP_HOST/DIR?username=???&password=???)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me on this. One followup question. Currently I am checking for `filePathObj` and starting `ftp-route`. I would like to do _onCompletion_ of route1. Is this the correct way to do.            `exchange.addOnCompletion(new Synchronization() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Exchange exchange) {
                    camelContext.addRoutes(ftpRouteBuilder);
                    camelContext.startRoute("rmaftpRoute");
                    template.send("direct:ftp-send", exchange);
}`

Comment: Not really - you should add and start your `ftpRouteBuilder` at the same time as you do the `generateFileRoute`. Also, there's no need for onCompletion here - `direct` routes are synchronous, meaning when `template.request` returns your exchange, the route has already finished. But there's no need for so much manual work - you can call `direct:ftp-send` from your first route. Just add `.to("direct:ftp-send")` at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Can't the ftpRoute simply poll fileDirLoc for new files ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround, you can try to combine them:

```
from("direct:start")
    .routeId("generateFileRoute")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple(URL))
    .setHeader("Authorization", simple(APP_KEY))
    .to(URL)
    .unmarshal(listJacksonDataFormat)
    .marshal(bindyCsvDataFormat)
    .to(fileUri.getUri())
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, file.getName())
    .to("sftp://FTP_HOST/DIR?username=???&password=???);
```

Yes, you cannot have dynamic expressions in the file uri but you can generate the uri and filename somewhere else. Say a utility method or something and refer to it here.